# "Added support for" or "added support of"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

If I add a new feature (called "feature X") to existing software, what do I say about the action?

> I added support for feature X

or

> I added support of feature X

?

Or something different?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither one.  You're not adding ***support*** of the feature; you're adding the feature itself.

First, let's address your premise:

> *If I add a new feature (called "feature X") to an existing software...*

should be either:

> - *If I add a new feature (called "feature X") to existing software...*
>
> or:
>
> - *If I add a new feature (called "feature X") to an existing software application*...

(Either eliminate the "*an*", or change "*software*" to its adjective form.  "*An existing software*" sounds off.)

Now, to answer your question, simply say:

> - *I added feature X to the software*.
>
> or
>
> - *I added feature X to the software application*.

As for when to use the word ***support***: if feature X had already been added, and support for the feature was added some months later, you might say:

> - *I added support for feature X in the software*.

(I'm assuming that **feature** refers to some new capability, and **support** refers to some support for that capability, such as built-in help menus.)

Comment: A little more context: I made the software support a new feature. This software reads the output of another one. That output has changed because feature X was added. My addition to my software is to support that new feature.

Comment: In that case, you could simply say, "_Feature X is now supported_" - I think.  (It's a little hard to follow your added context).

Answer (score 1):

They mean different things. *I added support for feature X* means that your contribution improved feature X in some way. *I added support of feature X* means that you added feature X to something else which in some way supported it. It sounds as if it's the second one that you want if you're adding it to existing software. If so, it would be preferable to precede 'support' with the definite article: *I added **the** support of feature X*.

Answer (score 1):

In the software context, *support for feature X* is used to mean that feature X can now be implemented. For example, in the LaTeX editor TeXworks, support for synctex has been added. This means that TeXworks is now built so that it works with synctex.