# "X support for Y" or "Y support for X" for "X supports Y"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, software

Please see the following two sentences:

- JSON support for MySQL has been developed.
- MySQL support for JSON has been developed.

Which one of this is correct?

Background: MySQL is a database software. At some point, the MySQL database software was improved to support JSON as a data format. Now MySQL supports JSON. I am unable to decide which grammatical consruct is correct or more appropriate to describe this situation: "JSON support for MySQL" or "MySQL support for JSON".

In general, if X supports Y, do we say "X support for Y is present" or "Y support for X is present"?

On reading https://english.stackexchange.com/a/60073/18396 carefully, it appears that if X supports Y, then we should say "support for Y". This implies that "X support for Y" or "MySQL support for JSON" is correct.

Am I right?

Comment: The first one is correct.

Comment: From your details, I have no idea.

However, the juggler supports the balls… the pillars support the portico… the table supports the fruit.

Answer (score -1):

After reading your description, it's clear that MySQL was the one who developed the support for external JSON to work with it. JSON didn't get any developments for MySQL. So in this context, following is the correct sentence.

> JSON support for MySQL has been developed.

Comment: Here is what I find confusing: In your answer you first mention "support for external JSON". But later you say that "support for MySQL" is the correct form. They both seem inconsistent with each other.

Comment: What I meant is support for JSON is developed for MySQL. so developments were done on mysql